# How to get index in vhdl?

Tags: indexing, vhdl, xilinx, quartus

How to find index of isW(4) in vhdl because I do not need value , just index?
[image]

Comment: The index of `W(4)` is 4??

Comment: but i need that number to put in one value

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Is the number 4 not "one value"?

Comment: The picture you show is of part of an interface list. The interface element isW is of mode in and can't be assigned within a corresponding architecture or subprogram body (*put in one value*).  What problem are you trying to solve? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pictures of code don't allow a reader to replicate a problem, nor is your actual problem conveyed here.

Comment: For your question [you just deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888640/10500-vhdl-error-near-text-when-expecting) I was about to vote to close as a duplicate. See [VHDL sequential conditional signal assignment statement error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388624/vhdl-sequential-conditional-signal-assignment-statement-error).